# Why does kubectl create only support certain resources?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm looking to create yaml files for specific resources (pvs, pvcs, policies and so on) via the command line with `kubectl`.

`kubectl create` only supports the creation of certain resource types (namely  clusterroles, clusterrolebindings, configmaps, cronjobs, deployments, jobs, namespaces, pod disruption budgets, priorityclasses,  quotas, roles, rolebindings, secrets, services and serviceaccounts).

Why doesn't it support pods, pvs, pvcs, etc?

I know of `kubectl run --generator=run=pod/v1` for pods, but is there a specific reason it  hasn't been added to `kubectl create`?

I searched the docs and github issues, but couldn't find an explanation.

I know of tools like ksonnet, but I was wondering if there is a native way (or a reason why there isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create **any type** of object with `kubectl create`. To do that you have two solutions :

1. Using a file descriptor : `kubectl create -f my-pod-descriptor.yml`
2. Using stdin (where your file content is in fact in your console) :

```sh
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox-sleep
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    args:
    - sleep
    - "1000000"
EOF
```

Now back to the question, as to why didn't they add a `kubectl create pod` command for example. I don't really have the answer.
My guess is because it is not really a good practice to manage **pods** directly. It is recommended to use **deployments** instead. And you have a `kubectl create deployment` command.

What about other objects wich are perfectly fine such as **pv or pvc**. Well, I don't know :)

Just keep in mind that it is not really a good practice to create/manage everything from the console, as you won't be able to keep the history of what you are doing. Prefer using files managed in a SCM.

Thus, I guess the K8S team is not putting too much an effort in a procedure or command that is not recommended. Which is fine to me.

Comment: I was using `kubectl create` to create minimal yaml-files, so using the `-f` flag kinda defeats the purpose for me.

Comment: You can use `kubectl run` in **dry-run** mode for that. Example for a pod running nginx : `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --dry-run -o yaml --generator=run-pod/v1`

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my question ;)

Comment: Then, i'm not really sure i understand what you are looking for...  If you want to **create** a resource using `kubectl create` then you'll have to do it with a file descriptor. But if you want to **generate** the minimal configuration, then you'll have to use `kubectl run --dry-run`.

Comment: `kubectl run` or `kubectl create` both don't give me the ability to e.g. create persistent volume yaml files. I only mentioned the `kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1` because that at least solves the pod yaml. I'll edit the question to make it a bit clearer!

Comment: Well then I don't have any other supposition about that (except the on I mentionned in my original response about depreciation and best practices). Sorry !

Comment: Probably the best guess :)